# Confusing efficiency and evaluation when returning pure functions?

Tags: functions, evaluation, pure-function

I have a function that takes some time to evaluate, that's meant to be a polynomial approximation to a function. The polynomial is defined by a list of coefficients, so I have the function "polynomial" which turns a list of coefficients and a variable into a polynomial. The function polynomialFunctionFitInterval comes up with a fit to the function f, that is a polynomial of degree "degree", on the interval (a,b), and I want it to return an anonymous function. This is what I have so far:

```
polynomial[clist_, x_] := 
  Sum[clist[[i]] x^(i - 1), {i, 1, Length[clist]}];
polynomialFunctionFitInterval[f_, degree_, a_, b_] := 
  Module[{f2, p, x},
   f2 = f[(b - a) # + a] &;
   polynomial[
     LinearSolve[HilbertMatrix[degree + 1], 
      Table[NIntegrate[x^n f2[x], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 0, degree}]],
     (# - a)/(b - a)
     ] &
   ];
```

So, since the coefficients of the polynomial are the result of a simple but non-trivial calculation, the coefficients really should only be evaluated once, but I can't seem to control the evaluation!

What I've got to work so far is this: If I want to approximate $\sin(\pi x)$ with a 6th degree polynomial, on the interval $(0,2)$, and plot the result, this runs, and it runs fast:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  polynomialFunctionFitInterval[Sin[Pi #] &, 6, 0, 2][x]], {x, -0.5, 
  2.5}]
```

*Timing: 0.109201*

However, this runs painfully slow:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[
  polynomialFunctionFitInterval[Sin[Pi #] &, 6, 0, 2][x]],Sin[Pi x]}, {x, -0.5, 
  2.5}]
```

*Timing: 44.678686*

So does removing the evaluate:

```
Plot[
  polynomialFunctionFitInterval[Sin[Pi #] &, 6, 0, 2][x], {x, -0.5, 
  2.5}]
```

The third code snippet I can understand running slow, because the coefficients could be re-evaluated each function call. What I don't understand is why the second code snippet is slow. I didn't remove an evaluate! I'm also confused as to why it doesn't seem like placing an evaluate anywhere inside polynomialFunctionFitInterval helps.

---

Note: I think this is the key to [a previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20564/a-is-fast-b-is-fast-but-together-theyre-mathematica-crashing-slow) of mine. Also, yes, I'm a mathematica newbie (only been through one and a half books on the subject), I actually need to read something on scope and evaluation order soon :\

Comment: Seems you can avoid all your trouble by just using the `Evaluated->True` option of `Plot`.

Comment: @Neuro Please read the answer of me here: [ParametricPlot3D doesn't appear](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21447/parametricplot3d-doesnt-appear) and you'll see, that your question is a duplicate of it.

Comment: Oh, so putting Evaluate[] at the head of the list of functions, like so: `Plot[Evaluate[{polynomialFunctionFitInterval[Sin[Pi #] &, 6, 0, 2][x], Sin[Pi x]}], {x, -0.5, 2.5}]` comes up with the desired result. (So does `Evaluated->True`). You're right, this is a duplicate, this suffers from the same problem as what you linked.